# List firewalls on the local machine

Tags: firewall, iptables

In Windows besides the Windows firewall a user could have installed a firewall program, or there is another service listening to that port.

In Ubuntu how can I see what blocks/filters open ports? Iptables rules? What about outbound connections?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To list rules on local machine use

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

Ubuntu is shipped with firewall(`ufw`), which is not enabled by default

- To check status of firewall:`sudo ufw status`
- To enable: `sudo ufw enable`
- To disable: `sudo ufw disable`
- To allow traffic on port: `sudo ufw allow <port_num>`
- To block a port: `sudo ufw block <port_num>`

To check what outbound connections are running use command

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n
```

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, all the firewalls are actually interfaces to setting up the rules of the kernel iptables.

To list all rules, type

```
sudo iptables -S
```

You can also see what firewall packages are installed by writing

```
dpkg -l | grep -i firewall
```

Comment: What happens in systems where iptables is not installed? Is there any other way to list the kernel iptables?